# What is the best way to add views ? dynamically or through XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout in which the there can be multiple number of views(The exact number is decided dynamically).For example i have a **layout** in which it should contain **5 Views** in one condition and in other condition it should contain **4** and in the other it may contain **3** etc.,I know of two approaches to do it. I have listed both of them below but i am just unsure as to which is a good practice.

**Approaches**

1: Adding the view dynamically to the layout using a loop.

2: Adding all possible views in the layout and make them **INVISIBLE,GONE,VISIBLE,** based on the condition's.

Which approach is better than the other and is there any performance difference between the above approaches?

Comment: If the views are of the same kind, it might be worth (from a design point of view) using an adapter (e.g. RecyclerView).

Comment: i am not using any listview, it is just a plain layout.

Comment: But you could. However for 3-5 views there should be no big performance differences.

Comment: I would use 2 because your code is much cleaner and simple.

Answer (score 0):

That is required on the basis of situations.
If you don't have any idea,how many views you need at run time.Then dynamic is the best.
If you have finite number of view that use xml for that work.
both are same,but make sense according to the situations.

in your case dynamic views are best.

1. get the count of views you need to create.
2. loop it and get the type you want to create dynamically.
3. create and add it to parent layout.

i think you need this kind of scenario

```
for(List num: list){
          if(num.gettype().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){ 
                 // add view
             }else if(num.gettype().equalsIgnoreCase("A")){ 
                 // add view
             }else if(num.gettype().equalsIgnoreCase("E")){ 
                 // add view
             }else ...
}
```

something like

Comment: what if i have to show a max of 8 views and in one condition show just one view and in another show  7 ?.i have to to set the visibility status of 7 views to Invisible or gone for first condition. would that be a good approach ?

Comment: how you are deciding the number of views?

Comment: could you please tell me what how performance is affected  if i use views via xml ?

Comment: it is webservice related :)

Comment: and what if you have created 8 views in xml and get 9 in web service?

Answer (score 0):

I wuold say, this is more of a design level question.

If your design follows MVC pattern, the views must be representing some objects which are maintained in your model. Please consider the backing objects (model objects) of these views and decide based upon real use cases.

Now, coming to your approaches:

Adding views dynamically to a layout is fine. You need to carefully remove every view from the layout if your use cases demands frequent addition and removal of them - simply because you can not add a child view to parent twice.

I would not recommend managing views using visibility attributes. Your logic to manually keep track of the state of all the views will be complicated as soon as you add more views and your whenever your use cases changes.

Again, I would say, consider making your design foolproof first following some common patterns like MVC - which will greately simplify your implementation and you can save yourself from many common pitfalls. (e.g. a phone orientation change and your activity restarting... etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague!
Are you referring to efficiency in programming effort?
If yes, then you can choose any approach based on the number of views. Dynamically adding views are good if the number of views changes during runtime. But, if it is static then you should prefer adding them through xml. 
Moreover, if you know the maximum number of views then your can simply all of them in xml and during runtime just set the visibility as Gone (if you don't want to show blank space) or Invisible (if you want to show the blank space).

Or maybe you're referring to the performance! Is it? It would be great if you explain the question in detail.